# What is the complexity of copying a variable in C++

Tags: c++, time-complexity

A friend of mine said that bitmasks are better than bitsets because it takes O(N) time to copy a bitset whereas only O(1) time to copy a bitmask, making it far faster for applications such as in Dynamic Programming. So I was wondering is it the same for all other data types?

For eg what would be the complexity of this block of code?

```
vector <int> vec1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
vector <int> vec2 = vec1;
```

If it is O(N), why is it so? Shouldn't it be O(1) just like doing something like

```
int x = 530210;
int y = x;
```

would be?

Comment: You're copying each element so it's O(n). If vec2 was a reference then it would be O(1) (but then it wouldn't be a copy). The int copy is O(1) because int has constant size. An AP int would be O(n).

Comment: Simple hint waiting for a better answer: are performance the same if vector has, 100 elements? Or 1000? Or 1000000? **Roughly** that's why N.

Comment: The simple way of copying N elements of a vector is a loop with N assignments.   Hence O(N).   However, there are other ways (e.g. copying a larger block of memory), but that doesn't work (undefined behaviour) for all possible element types (e.g. elements of the vector are objects with a non-trivial constructor/destructor).

Comment: Theoretically, copying bitsets and bitmasks is **also** O(N). Only the multiplicative constant is small because each word in the hardware contains a number of bits (say 32 or 64) and can be copied in a single operation.

Comment: If you were to write a vector-like class, and implemented a copy operation, how could you possibly do this without copying every element? Or more generally, how could you possibly copy 10 things at 10 different memory locations to 10 different other memory locations in *one* step?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have `vec1` which is a `std::vector<T>` represented by this truck with a *black-container* attached to its trailer.

[image]

*(source: bigcommerce.com)*

Now, there are millions of papers in its *black-container* (by *black-container*, `std::vector<T>`'s memory for the elements). Now, you want to photocopy the papers into another similar vehicle, `vec2`. How best can you do it? What is the photo-**copy** complexity? It is going to be *O(Number of papers)*

---

Now, assuming you want to **move** the contents... All `std::vector` needs to do is to detach its *black-container* from the truck, and attach it into another truck's... That makes **move** complexity of the container to be *O(1)*

Comment: Containers don't tend to be *welded* to prime movers.

Comment: @Peter. I've reworded my analogy using. Perhaps I need to reword it further?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the complexity of an operation, you first have to define your model of computation. In particular, you have to define what operations are O(1) and what operations you consider free.

For example, if you are looking at programs needing a lot of hard disk access, you would only consider reading a block from disk as one operation and memory access as free.

In the example of bitmasks and bitssets, you are probably counting memory block copy operations. Then copying a bit mask that fits into one memory block costs only one memory copy. However, copying bitmasks is still O(N) in this model because a large bitmask will span many memory blocks. More precisely, if b is the number of bits in one block of memory and N the number of bits in the bitmask, then you need ceil(N/b) memory block copy operations to copy the bitmask.

Answer (score 1):

Copying a vector of length `N` can be measured in several ways:

- `O(1)` vector copy operations
- `O(N)` element copy operations
- `O(NT)` units of measure, if the element copy operation is `O(T)`

Incidentally, your friend is wrong about `bitset`, or you misunderstood. The advantage of `bitset` is that the data structure is optimized to take advantage of a low level form of parallel execution that can be done by a single thread — i.e. 64-bit integer operations can be used to work on 64 different bits simultaneously.